# How to correctly annotate a csv file for uploading into a bucket in InfluxDB

Tags: csv, file-upload, influxdb

I am trying to evaluate InfluxDB as a real time, time series data visualization tool. I have an account with InfluDB and I have created a bucket for data storage.  I now want to upload a csv file into the bucket via the click to upload feature but I keep getting errors associated with incorrect annotations.  The last error I received was:

'*Failed to upload the selected CSV: error in csv.from(): failed to read metadata: failed to read header row: wrong number of fields*'

I have tried to decipher their docs and examples on how to annotate a csv file and have tried many different combinations of #datatype, #group and #default but nothing works.

```
This is the latest attempt that generated the error above.

#datatype,string,string,double,dateTime
#group,true,true,false,false
#default,,,,
_measurement,station,_value,_time
device,MBL,-0.814075542,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.837942395,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.862699339,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.891686336,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.891492408,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.933193098,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.933193098,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.976859072,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-0.981019863,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-1.011647128,1.65E+18
device,MBL,-1.017813258,1.65E+18
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data above, I assume "device" is the name of a measurement and "MBL" is a tag whose name is station. Hence, there is 1 measurement and 1 tag, 1 field and a timestamp.

And you are mixing data types and line protocol elements when using annotated CSV. You could try following version:

```
#datatype,measurement,tag,double,dateTime
#default device,MBL,
thisIsYouMeasurementName,station,thisIsYourFieldKeyName,time
device,MBL,-0.814075542,1652669077000000000
device,MBL,-0.837942395,1652669077000000001
device,MBL,-0.862699339,1652669077000000002
device,MBL,-0.891686336,1652669077000000003
device,MBL,-0.891492408,1652669077000000004
device,MBL,-0.933193098,1652669077000000005
device,MBL,-0.933193098,1652669077000000006
device,MBL,-0.976859072,1652669077000000007
device,MBL,-0.981019863,1652669077000000008
device,MBL,-1.011647128,1652669077000000009
device,MBL,-1.017813258,1652669077000000010
```

Note that time column should avoid using "1.65E+18". See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/syntax/annotated-csv/#mixing-data-types-and-line-protocol-elements).